# 小塚ゴシックの埋め込みができない

Tags: java, font

小塚ゴシックのフォントを埋め込みしたいですが、 埋め込み処理が正常に処理されません。
埋め込みPDFをAdobe Acrobat Reader DC で開くと以下のようなエラーになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、フォントのプロパティは以下のようになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Chromeで埋め込みPDFを開くと埋め込みできているか不明ですが、エラーがなく文字が表示されます。

OpenFunXion for iText というPDF作成ツールを使用して、javaで埋め込みの実装をしています。
使用している itext は、 itext-1.4.2 です。

ソースコードは以下です。

```
ofx.getText("head_titile").setExternalFontEnable(true);
                        ofx.getText("head_titile").setExternalFontFile(strPdfFont);
                        ofx.getText("head_titile").setExternalFontName("小塚ゴシック Pr6N medium");
                        ofx.getText("head_titile").setFontEncoding("Identity-H");
```

上記のバージョンのPDF作成エンジンを調べたいのですが、何を確認すればよいかわかりません。 ご教示お願いします。

Comment: 「正常に処理されません。」の具体的な内容とソースコードを質問に追記してください。

Comment: 質問を修正しました。確認お願いできますでしょうか？

Comment: 他のフォントであれば、問題なく表示されるのですか？

Comment: 2枚目の画像を見てもらえば分かると思いますが、IPAフォントは埋め込みでき、問題なく表示されました。

Comment: `strPdfFont`の値は何ですか？IPAフォントの場合と比較して、Javaの実装に違いは無いですか？

Comment: `strPdfFont`の値は、フォントファイルのフルパスとなっています。IPAフォントの場合との実装の違いはないです。

Comment: エラーメッセージはAdobe Acrobat Readerが出力しているので、Javaの実装の問題ではないかもしれないですね。有料フォントなので、何らかの制限がかかっているとか（分かりませんが...）。

Comment: http://neareal.com/843/ ←このサイトでは、小塚系のフォントの埋め込みは一部の環境に限定されると記載されていますが、それが本当かがわからないので、iText の作成エンジンを調べたいです。

Comment: かなり古いバージョンのiTextを使用されているようなので、新しいバージョンでも同様の事象が発生するのか確認してみるのもいいかもしれません。あとは他のいくつかのフォントで事象が発生するのか確認してみるとか。

Comment: 他のフォントの埋め込みを試してみました。おそらく小塚ゴシックは、OpenType型のPostscriptベースのフォントなので、埋め込みができないのではと仮定しました。OpenType型のPostscriptベースの他のフォントも試してみましたが、同様の事象が発生しました。何か解決策などありましたらご教示お願いします。

Comment: Adobeサポート（コミュニティ）に質問してみるとか...ですかね

Comment: 既に質問してみました。iTextのPDF作成エンジンを確認してみてくださいとの回答を頂いたので、その確認方法が分からず、ここで質問しました。itextのバージョンをあげて試してみたいのですが、無料のiTextのjarファイルをダウンロードできるサイトがあれば教えてください。

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases)からダウンロードできます。※ちなみに私はiTextを使ったことが無いので、詳しいことは` README.md`を確認して下さい。

Comment: iTextのバージョンをあげてみました。itext-4.2.0 と itext-5.0.1 を試してみましたが、どちらも同様の事象が発生しました。何か解決策などありましたらご教示お願いします。

Comment: Javaのプログラム内でエラーになっているわけではないので、Java側から問題を解決するのは難しいと考えます。生成されたPDFをAcrobat Readerが正常に表示できない理由をAdobeサポートに聞いてみることをお勧めします。その結果、「この属性がセットされていないため」というようなことが分かれば、iTextのソースコードを調査できると思います。

Comment: https://community.adobe.com/t5/Acrobat-Reader/Acrobat-Reader-DC%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%8B%E3%82%81%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/m-p/10660309#M58861

Comment: 上記のサイトで、Adobeサポートに問い合わせを行いました。その結果、iTextのエンジンを確認してみてくださいとのことでしたので、ここで質問しました。

Comment: 「生成されたPDFをAcrobat Readerが正常に表示できない理由が何なのかをもう少し具体的にご教示お願いできますでしょうか？」この回答次第ですね。